# How to get instagram access token using angular during implicit oauth?

Tags: angularjs, oauth, token, instagram

Since this application is meant to run without server support and I'm using Angular I can't catch implicit oauth token because Angular won't tolerate second hashbang (#) in URL.

Instagram is redirecting user back to http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/oauth/#access_token=TOKEN and Angular automatically redirect's back to http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/

My code for routing:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/index/index.html',
        controller: 'IndexController',
        controllerAs: 'index'
    })
    .when('/oauth/:token', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/oauth/index.html',
        controller: 'OAuthController',
        controllerAs: 'oauth'
    });

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

Is there a way I can remove # before Angular figures it out or force angular to ignore #?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its unclear what your trying to acheive in total here but I have a couple of nuggets that might help.

1) Remove the hash by using html 5 mode.
(In your app.config block...)

```
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

And in your index.html set an appropriate base href...

```
<base href="/" target="_blank">
```

2) I was buggering around with this ridiculous scenario for ages only to discover slightly undocumented if you just want a feed, you can grab a  users last 20 posts with a service that calls http like...

```
 $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/media',
    responseType: 'json'
  })
```

No clientid or secret needed.
No access token needed.